# Laravel 5 Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

How can i get the id of `$previous` variable. When i try to get it as i mentioned below i am getting

> Trying to get property of non-object

error on line 3. Any help would be appreciated.

```
$vehicle = Vehicle::find($id);

$previous = Vehicle::where('id', '<', $vehicle->id)->max('id');

if ($previous -> id == 3) {
    $previous = Vehicle::find(3);
}
```

Comment: which one is line 3?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you don't have a Vehicle with the given id `$id`. So then your `$previous` is null. Hence, you get that error. It's a runtime error and you should examine your database, in particular your `vehicles` table.

Try this and look at the result:

```
$vehicle = Vehicle::find($id);
dd($vehicle);
$previous = Vehicle::where('id', '<', $vehicle->id)->max('id');

if ($previous -> id == 3) {
    $previous = Vehicle::find(3);
}
```

I believe you won't get a Collection object back.

Answer (score 0):

Always check if you got an object or `null`.

```
$vehicle = Vehicle::find($id);

if ($vehicle) {
    $previous = Vehicle::where('id', '<', $vehicle->id)->max('id');

    // other code
}
else {
    // do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are using an aggregate function `max`. So the returned value is not an object but the max value as a string.

You could simply do,

```
if ($previous == 3) {
    $previous = Vehicle::find(3);
}
```

or the following

```
$previous = Vehicle::where('id', '=', function($query) use ($vehicle) 
{
    $query->from(with(new Vehicle)->getTable())
          ->select(DB::raw('max(id)'))
          ->where('id', '<', $vehicle->id);
})->first();
```

Now you can perform `$previous->id`. No need for `$previous = Vehicle::find(3)`, because it already is the vehicle object of that `id`